# NuGet doesn't show installed packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I have MVC 5 project and I use NuGet to install packages. Yesterday I have installed a couple of packages, but today when I run my application I got an error of missing references. I've realized, that my project doesn't have any of references and files that were added from NuGet.I have all this packages in `packages` folder in my app, but no records about this packages in `packages.config` file. If I click `Manage NuGet Packages` in my solution explorer, in online search it shows me all my packages as `installed`, but in `all installed` tab it doesn't show me any of them! I didn't do anything since yesterday? What could happened and how to fix all my packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had this happen from time to time. There are two things that you can try:

1. Right click your solution in 'Solution Explorer' and select 'Enable NuGet Package Restore'
2. Close and Reopen VS
3. Try Rebuild

Otherwise, just uninstall/reinstall each package.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't see 'Enable NuGet Package Restore'. Fixed by closing visual studio and reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you added new package does't support to your .net framework which is currently active, so active related .net framework as well.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just have experienced the same problem. In my case, two different versions of a sample package in the packages.config file causing the problem. After removing the older version of the package from the file, VS shows the list normally.